# Android using Gradle Build flavors in the code like an if case

Tags: android, build, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to work with build flavors. In my build.gradle I've defined 2 flavors, a normal flavor and an admin flavor.

Basicly, the admin flavor has an extra button on the main activity.

I understand that I can define different packages/classes for different flavors. But is there a way to make a sort of if case to add/remove a piece of code depending on the flavor?

Basicly, I would need two versions of an Activity. But I don't want two entire different versions of the activity and maintain them.

So in my activity I would like to do

=> gradle check if flavor is 'admin'

=> if yes, add this code of the button

Is this possible? Or would you need two different physical activities and thus maintain both of them when you add functionality afterwards.

Comment: you can add just one line on onCreate of activity to do this: check the flavore and made a button invisible(GONE)

Comment: how would that line look like?

Comment: `if(!BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("admin")) { buttonTheOneWeWanaHide.setVisibility(View.GONE);}`

Answer (score 157, accepted):

`BuildConfig.FLAVOR` gives you combined product flavor.
So if you have only one flavor dimension:

```
productFlavors {
    normal {
    }

    admin {
    }
}
```

Then you can just check it:

```
if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("admin")) {
    ...
}
```

But if you have multiple flavor dimensions:

```
flavorDimensions "access", "color"

productFlavors {
    normal {
        dimension "access"
    }

    admin {
        dimension "access"
    }

    red {
        dimension "color"
    }

    blue {
        dimension "color"
    }
}
```

there are also `BuildConfig.FLAVOR_access` and `BuildConfig.FLAVOR_color` fields so you should check it like this:

```
if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR_access.equals("admin")) {
    ...
}
```

And `BuildConfig.FLAVOR` contains full flavor name. For example, `adminBlue`.

Comment: NOTE: `flavorDimension` was replaced by `dimension` in Gradle 2.0.

Comment: @mixel just out of curiosity, in this implementation, we need to include ALL logic into one single build. Any one can decompile the apk and rebuild if needed to simple change the boolean? Why not extract the logic and place the logic in different folder and use `souceSets` to decide which folder to fetch? in this way, there is no issue for exposing entire logic to the world.

Comment: @IHC_Applroid Yes. OP said: "I understand that I can define different packages/classes for different flavours", so I think it's not an option for him to place code in different `sourceSets`.

Comment: @IHC_Applroid the Idea was that if I need to build two separate Activities, and something needs to change, I would need to change it every time twice. This would decrease the maintainability of the application. Hence I was looking something like this.

Although I agree with the potential security risk you mentioned. But in my personal case I was willing to take that risk.

Comment: better to code this way `if ("admin".equals(BuildConfig.FLAVOR))` in case BuildConfig is null

Comment: @nuttynibbles In most cases I agree with you, but here I prefer application to throw a `NullPointerException` if `BuildConfig.FLAVOR` is null.

Comment: i need to do the same thing but in another module, like my product falvors are defined in the main module's(app) build.gradle, but how can i get the flavour value in my other module(ex: library module)??

Answer (score 87):

To avoid plain string in the condition, you can define a boolean property:

```
productFlavors {
    normal {
        flavorDimension "access"
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_ADMIN', 'false'
    }

    admin {
        flavorDimension "access"
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_ADMIN', 'true'
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
if (BuildConfig.IS_ADMIN) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: When writing it, it's marked with line-through, which is deprecation. What should be used instead, and how?

Comment: I have kept a few strings like this in the build.gradle file but it doesn't tell me deprecation.

Comment: @androiddeveloper See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119557/android-using-gradle-build-flavors-in-the-code-like-an-if-case#comment73081757_30334392 (1st comment to the accepted answer)

Comment: @LoungeKatt So use "dimension" instead. OK.

Comment: The rest should still be current, but I only use one dimension. It was easier to stick with `BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals` in my code.

Comment: If you have N flavors then each should have N `buildConfigField` boolean constants, one of each constants set should be true and overs false . So it can get really messy in that case.

Comment: @user2878850 's answer is good. But if you want to avoid some warning like "Condition is always 'false'" , I prefer to write `buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_ADMIN', 'Boolean.parseBoolean("false")'` , this is also the compiler generate code of the  `BuildConfig.DEBUG`

Comment: This is an interesting response. But caution should be used when getting overly programmatic in any build script.

Answer (score 0):

You can define either different build configuration fields or different resource values (like string values) per flavor, e.g. (as per [Google's gradle tips and recipes](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips)), e.g.,

```
android {
  ...
  buildTypes {
    release {
      // These values are defined only for the release build, which
      // is typically used for full builds and continuous builds.
      buildConfigField("String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"${minutesSinceEpoch}\"")
      resValue("string", "build_time", "${minutesSinceEpoch}")
      ...
    }
    debug {
      // Use static values for incremental builds to ensure that
      // resource files and BuildConfig aren't rebuilt with each run.
      // If they were dynamic, they would prevent certain benefits of
      // Instant Run as well as Gradle UP-TO-DATE checks.
      buildConfigField("String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"0\"")
      resValue("string", "build_time", "0")
    }
  }
}
```

So in this case, something like

```
productFlavors {
    normal {
        dimension "access"
        buildConfigField("boolean", "IS_ADMIN", "false")
    }

    admin {
        dimension "access"
        buildConfigField("boolean", "IS_ADMIN", "true")
    }
}
```

and then use it like

```
if (BuildConfig.IS_ADMIN) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

or if it is just to have different string values for different flavors, it can be done with different `resValues` and then you don't even need the `if/then`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
   productFlavors {
    def app_name = "you app name"
    development {
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.1"          
        buildConfigField 'String', 'varibalename', ""           
    }

    release {
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.1"               
        buildConfigField 'String', 'varibalename', ""           
    }     
}
```

if(BuildConfig.varibalename){}