# Android flavor duplicate class

Tags: android, class, duplicates

Duplicate class error with product flavors.

I have deleted my mainActivity from Main and inserted a copy into both of my product flavor folders "free" and "paid".
But now inside the "free" flavor it says there is a duplicate inside "paid", and the same thing the other way around..
But am I not supposed to delete from main and insert a copy into all flavors I have?

Comment: WHy do you have separate folders for different flavors?  The idea of flavors is you use one codebase, not multiple.  Generally you'd have 1 activity that checks what flavor it is and changes its behavior accordingly. This way you don't duplicate the code and maintenance of common bugs.

Comment: It's because i need one java class with ads for my free flavor and one java class without ads for my paid version.

Comment: So you put the ads in both, and hide them in the paid version by setting its visibility to GONE.  Or you add them at runtime in the free version.  YOu do not use two activities, that's just asking for pain.

Comment: But how do I then make it act differently depending on which flavor it is?

Comment: Check BuildConfig.FLAVOR.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119557/android-using-gradle-build-flavors-in-the-code-like-an-if-case

Comment: now I have written this:

Comment: flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId "com.larsnyborgpedersen.meditationforboern2.free"
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'withAds', 'true'
            dimension "default"
        }

        paid {
            applicationId "com.larsnyborgpedersen.meditationforboern2.paid"
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'withAds', 'false'
            dimension "default"

        }
    }

Comment: But I can't access buildConfigField from my java code..... Even though I write if (BuildConfig.withAds)

Comment: Your original approach sounds good. Could you post the directory structure?