# How to build two build android variant for fetching two Different URL using Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, build-variant

I am developing an android application for fetching two different Rest API for two different Build Variant sharing the same DataSource. I am using product flavor for a build variant. But I don't know how to config the Retrofit portion for selecting different API for different build variant.

Thank in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android using Gradle Build flavors in the code like an if case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119557/android-using-gradle-build-flavors-in-the-code-like-an-if-case)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a [BuildConfig Field](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#simplify-app-development) to provide different **REST API URL** based on your product flavors to your API client:

Open your **build.gradle** *(app level)* file and add the following lines to your **android block**:

```
    android {
        ....
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            def variantName = variant.flavorName
            // replace your specific flavor here instead of 'flavor1' & 'flavor2'
            if (variantName.contains("flavor1")) { 
                variant.buildConfigField 'String', "SERVER_URL", '"your_flavor_specific_url_here"'
            } else if (name.contains("flavor2")) {
                variant.buildConfigField 'String', "SERVER_URL", '"your_flavor_specific_url_here"'
            }
        }
        ....
    }
```

Now **Rebuild your project** and then you can access **`BuidConfig.SERVER_URL`** in your project which will differ based on your product flavor you've selected.

Answer (score 0):

for debug release, you can use

```
        // setting up retrofit
        .baseUrl(if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            "https://debug.server"
        } else {
            "https://release.server"

        })
```

for flavor, you can try

```
        // setting up retrofit
        .baseUrl(if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR == "test") {
            "https://debug.server"
        } else if(BuildConfig.FLAVOR == "staging"){
            "https://staging.server"
        } else {
            "https://release.server"
        })
```

[This question describes how to define flavors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30334392/415673)